# How to use the ivy local repository as a maven respository

Tags: maven, ivy

The ivy local repository is in ~/.ivy2, and I'd like to use it as my local maven respoitory. Is there any easy way like setting to do it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect what you're trying to do is share ivy's cache, not it's local repository. Files are placed in ivy's repository by calling the [publish task](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/publish.html). Ivy has a clear storage distinction between these file types:

```
~/.ivy2/cache
~/.ivy2/local
```

Maven on the other hand mixes up both file types under the following directory:

```
~/.m2/repository
```

It would be a lot simpler to optimize your caching by installing a Maven repository manager like [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/) and configuring Maven and Ivy to use it. [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/) is a very efficient java process and simple to setup on your development machine.

Finally if you are determined to share caches, you could attempt to use the [caches](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/settings/caches.html) directive in the ivy settings file. It has "ivyPattern" and "artifactPattern" directives which suggest one can customize how the cached files are stored. To make this work you'll have to customize ivy. Maven has no flexibility in this area.